Shifter hood replacement, Shimano ST 4800
I want to replace the shifter hoods for my bike. I bought the bike in Japan in 2009. It's a Bridgestone Anchor CX900. I want to replace the hood for a Shimano Japan ST 4800 shifter. I can't find them anywhere, or I don't know where to search for them.
Do you know if I can use another model that would fit?

Could you show us a photo of the shifter? Which model line it is? The latest Tiagra is 4700.

Perhaps you mean ST-4500, which would have been current for a 2009 bike?  (Release in 2007.)

The brand of bike is way less important than the details of the brifter.  Can you please lift the lower edge of the existing rubber hoods, and photograph/note down the exact model number?   Likely of the format    ST-1230 or ST-R4560   or similar.

If your shifter is a ST-4800 then it probably looks like this:

and shimano calls their replacement rubber hoods "Bracket Covers"
I can find plenty that specify compatibility with "Shimano ST-6800/5800/4700" but not 4800.
